# Net Core API: Make ProducesResponseType Global Parameter or Automate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, inheritance, .net-core

We have 100+ APIs and have to write ProducesResponseType for all our APIS at the top, 200, 500, etc. Is there a method to make this global parameter for all our get functions, so we don't have to continue repeating code? Trying to make APIs follow Dry principle and be thin controllers.

```
[HttpGet("[Action]/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GetBookResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GetBookResponse), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<GetBookResponse>> GetByBook(int id)
{
   var book = await bookservice.GetBookById(id);
   return Ok(book);
}
```

**Resources:**

[Set one ProducesResponseType typeof for several HttpStatusCodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153621/set-one-producesresponsetype-typeof-for-several-httpstatuscodes)

[Net Core API: Purpose of ProducesResponseType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678813/net-core-api-purpose-of-producesresponsetype)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a custom `IApplicationModelProvider` and add the filters you need in `OnProvidersExecuting` method.

**ProduceResponseTypeModelProvider.cs**

```
public class ProduceResponseTypeModelProvider : IApplicationModelProvider
{
    public int Order => 3;

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
        foreach (ControllerModel controller in context.Result.Controllers)
        {
            foreach (ActionModel action in controller.Actions)
            {
                // I assume that all you actions type are Task<ActionResult<ReturnType>>

                Type returnType = action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetGenericArguments()[0];

                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status510NotExtended));
                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(returnType, StatusCodes.Status200OK));
                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(returnType, StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it to `IServiceCollection`

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...   
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IApplicationModelProvider, ProduceResponseTypeModelProvider>());
    ...
}
```

Comment: also what does public int Order => 3 do? don't see it used it code, everything else looks good

Comment: It's all in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iapplicationmodelprovider. `Order` property is for when you have multiple `IApplicationModelProvider` and you can set which one runs first. `3` is just a random number!

Comment: hi, sometimes when I run this for my api projects, I get this error, I look at the particular API and it has no [0] index, however the API controller exists, not sure why property isn't showing up, is there alternative? "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"

Comment: I think it can be simplied, trying to find typeof (GetBookResponse), etc

Comment: have question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671768/net-core-find-api-status-codes-for-controller-actionmodel

Comment: Since I don't need returnType, except on "200 OK" and I use that one on the controller and not here I have modified the code and mine looks like this:
            `foreach (ControllerModel controller in context.Result.Controllers)
            {
                foreach (ActionModel action in controller.Actions)
                {
                    action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent));
                    action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest));    
     ...
                }
            }`

Answer (score 1):

Kahbazi answer is the correct, we also use this line of code,
It provides error handling, verb attribute check, and if parameters exist,

```
public class ProduceResponseTypeModelProvider : IApplicationModelProvider
    {
        public int Order => 3;

        public void OnProvidersExecuted(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
        {
        }

        public void OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
        {
            foreach (ControllerModel controller in context.Result.Controllers)
            {
                foreach (ActionModel action in controller.Actions)
                {
                    Type returnType = null;
                    if (action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments.Any())
                    {
                        if (action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetGenericArguments().Any())
                        {
                            returnType = action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        }
                    }

                    var methodVerbs = action.Attributes.OfType<HttpMethodAttribute>().SelectMany(x => x.HttpMethods).Distinct();
                    bool actionParametersExist = action.Parameters.Any();

                    AddUniversalStatusCodes(action, returnType);

                    if (actionParametersExist == true)
                    {
                        AddProducesResponseTypeAttribute(action, null, 404);
                    }
                    if (methodVerbs.Contains("POST"))
                    {
                        AddPostStatusCodes(action, returnType, actionParametersExist);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddProducesResponseTypeAttribute(ActionModel action, Type returnType, int statusCodeResult)
        {
            if (returnType != null)
            {
                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(returnType, statusCodeResult));
            }
            else if (returnType == null)
            {
                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(statusCodeResult));
            }
        }

        public void AddUniversalStatusCodes(ActionModel action, Type returnType)
        {
            AddProducesResponseTypeAttribute(action, returnType, 200);
            AddProducesResponseTypeAttribute(action, null, 500);
        }

        public void AddPostStatusCodes(ActionModel action, Type returnType, bool actionParametersExist)
        {
            AddProducesResponseTypeAttribute(action, returnType, 201);
            AddProducesResponseTypeAttribute(action, returnType, 400);
            if (actionParametersExist == false)
            {
                AddProducesResponseTypeAttribute(action, null, 404);
            }
        }
    }
```