# Find API Status Codes for Controller ActionModel

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Improving upon this question, how do I Find All the Existing Status Codes for ActionModel action in ApplicationModelProvider, before adding them?

Currently looking through `action.Filters[0].StatusCode` in debugger,  however cannot access the property in actual code.
Need to see what Status codes already exist for API Controller Actions in all **array** list, before adding it .

did  filters[0] as a test

[Net Core API: Make ProducesResponseType Global Parameter or Automate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047020/net-core-api-make-producesresponsetype-global-parameter-or-automate)

```
    foreach (ControllerModel controller in context.Result.Controllers)
    {
        foreach (ActionModel action in controller.Actions)
        {
            Type returnType = action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetGenericArguments()[0];

            action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status510NotExtended));
            action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(returnType, StatusCodes.Status200OK));
            action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(returnType, StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError));
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...   
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IApplicationModelProvider, ProduceResponseTypeModelProvider>());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First cast as ProducesResponseTypeAttribute, and get StatusCode
See code below,

```
foreach (var filter in action.Filters)
{
    if (filter.GetType() == typeof(ProducesResponseTypeAttribute))
    {
         var producesResponseTypeAttribute = (filter as ProducesResponseTypeAttribute)
         var statusCode = producesResponseTypeAttribute.StatusCode;
```