# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers - Is there a configuration for detecting global "ProducesResponseType" attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

After enabling Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers in an .NET Core 3.1 application, and applying the following filters on top of an action-method that produces those types of return codes it works as expected: It produces a warning if a response code attribute is missing and they go away if they do not.

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [AuthorizeAllRoles]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(string))]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething(string id)
        {
            //.. does stuff and returns other action types
            await Task.Run(() =>{Thread.Sleep(1000);});
                
            return BadRequest("my error message");
        }
```

But the BadRequest response with an error message is common to all controllers in the project, so I **removed it from the controller** and **re-applied it as a global filter**. That also works. I can see those status codes in my Swagger documentation.

But the analyzer now produces a warning:
`API1000: "Action method returns undeclared status code '400'."`

It is the same result when the attribute is applied at controller-class level.

I can surpress these warnings of course.

The question is if I'm missing some configuration somewhere for the analyser to detect those global or class level attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is an [open issue in app.net core](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20662).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047020/net-core-api-make-producesresponsetype-global-parameter-or-automate).

> You can create a custom IApplicationModelProvider and add the filters you need in OnProvidersExecuting method.

About [IApplicationModelProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iapplicationmodelprovider).

Comment: Basically what I'm doing to cause the issue. The issue is that the api-analyzer does not recognize the attributes unless they are applied directly to the action-methods. Found that it is an open issue (see link in my own answer).