# .net Core - Response type is ignored when add Filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

In `startup.cs` I add filter for all Error response, bcs I return own error object (ErrorResponse) by throw exception and in middleware I return this code in response. But these errors are not as a return type in controllers methods so I have to add filter to all responses. It works and in swagger.json are these responses but without response type (200) there are only error responses.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
 options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
 options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ErrorResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
 options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ErrorResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
 options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ErrorResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
 options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ErrorResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
})
```

[image: sample image]

Does anybody know how can I preserve default return type from controllers methods?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: Either use `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute` or `ActionResult<T>` as a return type

Comment: I use this - `public async Task<ActionResult<HorseEntity>> GetHorseById(int id)` , and in swagger.json is not these type even 200 return

Comment: I think this is a useful question and I have the same issue as @Merynek. If I use o.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ValidationProblemDetails), 400)) in AddControllers my method return types are not read, regardless of them defined with ActionResult<T> or not. It could be nice to define globally for a project this ValidationProblemDetails 400 return type so it is confusing that that filter addition ruins the swagger

Answer (score -2):

While I am not entirely sure why it is that the filters end up removing the default 200 response type given by `ActionResult<T>`, here is another way that this can be done, albeit with more code. This code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58047598/2141621):

```
public class ProduceResponseTypeModelProvider : IApplicationModelProvider
{
    public int Order => 3;

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
        var actions = context.Result.Controllers
            .SelectMany(x => x.Actions);

        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            var returnType = action.ActionMethod.ReturnType;

            // if the action returns Task<T>, use that T as the return type
            if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
            {
                returnType = returnType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            }

            // if returnType is an ActionResult<T>, use that T for a 200 OK response
            if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ActionResult<>))
            {
                var innerReturnType = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(innerReturnType, StatusCodes.Status200OK));
            }
            // otherwise, if the type is only IActionResult, return 204 No Content
            else if (returnType == typeof(IActionResult))
            {
                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent));
            }

            // if there are input parameters, add 400 Bad Request as a possible result
            if (action.Parameters.Count > 0)
            {
                action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest));
            }

            // add common response types
            action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized));
            action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden));
            action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound));
            action.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError));
        }
    }
}
```

It should be fairly straightforward to see how you can adapt the above to return `ErrorResponse` for specific responses.

The above can be injected with:

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IApplicationModelProvider, ProduceResponseTypeModelProvider>());
```